# how to pipe ls -ltr after list of files to capture date and time

Tags: linux, command-line, pipe, ls

we have script that print all bad wsp files

```
 ./print_bad_wsp_files.sh



./aaaa/rrr/aaaa/fff/ooo/min.wsp
./aaaa/rrr/aaaa/fff/ooo/p50.wsp
./aaaa/rrr/aaaa/fff/ooo/min.wsp
./aaaa/rrr/aaaa/fff/ooo/p50.wsp

# ls -ltr

drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   36 Aug 14 14:58 aaaa
```

is it possible to pipe the script so I will get the ls -ltr results ? of each file?

I did that until now

```
 ./print_bad_wsp_files.sh | ls -ltr
```

but it give only

```
 drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   36 Aug 14 14:58 aaaa
```

while the expected results should be

```
 -rw-r--r-- 1 graphite mo 17308 Oct 11  2017 ./aaaa/rrr/aaaa/fff/ooo/min.wsp
 -rw-r--r-- 1 graphite mo 13508 Oct 11  2017 ./aaaa/rrr/aaaa/fff/ooo/p50.wsp
 -rw-r--r-- 1 graphite mo 27208 Oct 11  2017 ./aaaa/rrr/aaaa/fff/ooo/min.wsp
 -rw-r--r-- 1 graphite mo 19208 Oct 11  2017 ./aaaa/rrr/aaaa/fff/ooo/p50.wsp
```

Comment: the output is "one filename per line"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you may need here is `xargs`:

```
./print_bad_wsp_files.sh | xargs ls -ltr
```

xargs will read the output from the script and execute `ls -ltr` on all of them (potentially grouped in bunches, as many as will fit in each call to `ls`).

Note that if there are multiple calls to `ls`, each `ls` will sort its own list of files (by reverse time) separately.